# what to call viewDidLoad or loadview

Tags: iphone

I have a view controller class which loads from a .nib file. However, I also want to add controls (like UISwitch) to that view programmatically (UISwitch is not added to the nib file). In which portion of my code should I allocate the UISwitch control, viewDidLoad or loadView method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `viewDidLoad`.  Additionally you should remove everything you added in the `viewDidUnload` method.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it on viewDidLoad. Definitely.

From Apple's documentation:

> Discussion 
>   This method is only invoked
>   when the view property is nil and it
>   is needed for display. You should not
>   invoke this method directly.
>
> If you create the view that this view
>   controller manages programmatically,
>   then you should override this method
>   to create your view. The default
>   implementation creates a UIView object
>   with no subviews.
>
> However, if you initialize the view
>   using a nib file—that is, you set
>   thenibName and nibBundle
>   properties—then you should not
>   override this method because the
>   default implementation already reloads
>   the nib file. Instead override the
>   viewDidLoad method to set any
>   properties after the nib file is
>   loaded.

In your case, the UIView is being created from the **NIB** file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading from a NIB, implementing `loadView` will cause an error. Use `viewDidLoad`. As Pablo says, this is well documented by Apple.